# Multiplos Cmake em um projeto

Tags: c++, lib, cmake

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C++, onde necessito usar uma biblioteca que já desenvolvi antes com CMake. Mas não quero chamar diretamente o binário pois cada plataforma vai ter que ter um binário separadamente, e fica chato ter que compilar cada um para depois compilar o projeto, minha dúvida é a seguinte, tem como chamar o CMake do meu outro projeto para compilar a dependência para depois compilar este novo projeto já linkando a dependência? Se sim, como eu farei este milagre? Projeto que eu quero usar https://github.com/TigreFramework/String.
CMake do novo projeto que irá utilizar este acima:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(DataBase)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp DataBase.cpp DataBase.h String.h libString.a)
add_executable(DataBase ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pedro Soares,

Você precisa utilizar o `add_subdirectory(xpto)` no seu CMakeLists.txt principal.

Segue o post do meu blog ensinando como modularizar bibliotecas em C++.

https://fegomes.com/2018/03/09/como-modularizar-bibliotecas-em-c/

Pode ver o exemplo no repositório git do post acima:

https://github.com/fegomes/main

Abs,
Fernando Gomes